# How to return false from a for loop if any of the conditions are false

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, return, boolean

I'm working on a function which should return false if any of the point positions are outside of the defined rectangle boundaries.

My current c++ code is as follows:

```
bool trackingPointsVisible(){
        //I've got 4 points here
        if(!points.empty()){
              // loop through each of the points
            for(int i=0; i<points.size(); i++){
                   //check if points' x and y positions are out of the boundaries
                if(points[i].x < -60 || points[i].x > 300 ||
                points[i].y < -60 || points[i].y > 300){
                   // if any of them are out return false 
                    return false;
                }else{
                   //if they're within the boundaries, return true
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
  }
```

For some reason, it returns `true` even if one of the points if out of the specified boundaries. I don't think this should be the case. Should I rewrite this function and check each point individually or is there another approach?

Could anyone please point what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Beware that you have undefined behavior if `points` is empty, since on that path does not return. In any case, that `if` is redundant as the `for` loop will not run an iteration if `size` is 0 (`i` will never be less than `0`).

Comment: Are you sure that your condition is satisfied though? as your code looks correct to me so it looks like a data issue

Comment: Since you are asking for alternative approaches, [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) can easily be used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return based on the check of the first point, without proceeding to check any of the others.  You should return false if you find a point outside the region, otherwise continue to check the remaining points, only returning true outside the loop.

For whatever it's worth, you can simplify the code a bit:

```
bool trackingPointsVisible()
{
    for (const auto& point : points)
        //check if points' x and y positions are out of the boundaries
        if (point.x < -60 || point.x > 300 ||
            point.y < -60 || point.y > 300)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

...or, more declaratively...

```
bool trackingPointsVisible()
{
    // check none of the points are out of bounds...
    return std::none_of(std::begin(points), std::end(points),
                        [](const Point& point) {
                           return point.x < -60 || point.x > 300 ||
                                  point.y < -60 || point.y > 300;
                        });
}
```

Comment: I see where I've made the mistake now, also thanks for the simplified versions of code!

Answer (score 1):

First of all the function has undefined behavior because it returns nothing in case when the container `points` is empty.

Secondly you have to return true only if all points were checked. That is the return statement for true must be outside the loop.

The function can be defined the following way.

```
bool trackingPointsVisible()
{
        //I've got 4 points here
        size_t i = 0;

        while ( i < points.size() and not
                ( points[i].x < -60 || points[i].x > 300 ||
                  points[i].y < -60 || points[i].y > 300 ) ) i++;

        return i == points.size();
}
```

The declaration

```
size_t i = 0;
```

can be substituted for

```
decltype( points )::size_type i = 0;
```

For example

```
bool trackingPointsVisible()
{
        //I've got 4 points here
        decltype( points )::size_type i = 0;

        while ( i < points.size() and not
                ( points[i].x < -60 || points[i].x > 300 ||
                  points[i].y < -60 || points[i].y > 300 ) ) i++;

        return i == points.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return true only in the end of the function:

```
bool trackingPointsVisible(){
    //I've got 4 points here
    if(!points.empty()){
        // loop through each of the points
        for(int i=0; i<points.size(); i++) {
            //check if points' x and y positions are out of the boundaries
            if(points[i].x < -60 || points[i].x > 300 ||
            points[i].y < -60 || points[i].y > 300) {
               // if any of them are out return false 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```